# Oracle Advance Queue- Payload Type Issue (Nested Object Type)

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, user-defined-types, oracle-aq

I am trying to create Advance Queue table in Oracle. 
I created one object type and table type for Assets of Person (like Car, Bike, house) and another object type for Person (with column Name and Asset table type).

I need to store payload which would have nested details (Header and nested details). However I am getting below error while executing CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE:

```
ORA-22913: must specify table name for nested table column or attribute
ORA-06512: at “SYS.DBMS_AQADM”, line 81
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Execute Block:

```
begin
    DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (
        queue_table => 'sau_q_tab'
       , queue_payload_type => 'sau_person_o_type'
    );
end;
```

Object Type details:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sau_asset_o_type as object (
    asset_id number,
    asset_name varchar2(30),
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION sau_asset_o_type
        RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sau_asset_t_type AS TABLE OF sau_asset_o_type;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sau_person_o_type as object (
    person_name varchar2(30),
    person_assets sau_asset_t_type,
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION sau_person_o_type /*nested table type*/
         RETURN SELF AS RESULT);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY sau_person_o_type IS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION sau_person_o_type
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY sau_asset_o_type IS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION sau_asset_o_type
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
/
```

Comment: Do you have a pressing reason for using Types? Forget the ORDBMS hype: Oracle Types are good for programmatic constructs but not so good for data persistence. AQ implementations tend to use XML payloads, because they're just easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the name of your nested table using the [`storage_clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/clauses009.htm#SQLRF30013) parameter.

Since the corresponding column in the queue-table is called `user_data`, we need to use this column name:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (
        queue_table => 'sau_q_tab'
       , queue_payload_type => 'sau_person_o_type'
       , storage_clause     => 'NESTED TABLE user_data.person_assets STORE AS sau_q_nested'
    );
END;
```